Layout error with after compilation with custom Qiskit pass manager
I am trying to implement the custom Qiskit pass manager from this paper. The code from the authors is provided here on GitHub. I am able to get the pass manager working, and a compiled circuit is returned. However, when I try to send the job to a backend (namely, ibm_quebec), I receive this error:
qiskit.circuit.exceptions.CircuitError: "Could not locate provided bit: Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 1). Has it been added to the QuantumCircuit?"

The compiled circuit executes fine when run on an AerSimulator.
I believe this has something to do with the layout of the compiled circuit. Indeed, the error is raised when Qiskit internally loops over the qubits in the circuit.layout.final_layout object and tries to find each virtual bit in the qubits of the compiled circuit. The circuit.layout.final_layout object looks like this
Layout({
2: Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 2),
0: Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 1),
1: Qubit(QuantumRegister(3, 'q'), 0)
})

and these qubits are not in circuit.qubits. My code is here:
from qiskit import QuantumRegister
from qiskit.circuit.library import XGate
from qiskit.providers.models import BackendProperties
from qiskit.passmanager import DoWhileController
from qiskit.transpiler import PassManager, CouplingMap, Layout, InstructionDurations
from qiskit.transpiler.passes import (
    Depth,
    FixedPoint,
    Collect2qBlocks,
    ConsolidateBlocks,
    UnitarySynthesis,
    Optimize1qGatesDecomposition,
    SetLayout,
    FullAncillaAllocation,
    EnlargeWithAncilla,
    ApplyLayout,
    ALAPSchedule,
    DynamicalDecoupling,
)
from qiskit_bip_mapper.bip_mapping import BIPMapping


def qv_passmanager(
    basis_gates: list[str],
    coupling_map: CouplingMap,
    qubit_subset: list[int],
    backend_props: BackendProperties,
    instruction_durations: InstructionDurations,
    synthesis_fidelity: float,
    pulse_optimize: bool = True,
    bip_time_limit: int = 100,
) -> PassManager:
    '''
    A custom pass manager adapted from
        https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/cac5f9e1eea695324a71a9d7e9bf268131a1c62b/tutorials/circuits_advanced/qv_tools.py
    '''

    def _repeat_condition(property_set):
        return not property_set['depth_fixed_point']

    sub_coupling_map = coupling_map.reduce(mapping=qubit_subset)
    qr = QuantumRegister(size=len(qubit_subset), name='q')
    layout = Layout.from_intlist(sorted(qubit_subset), qr)

    _map = [BIPMapping(coupling_map=sub_coupling_map, objective='depth', time_limit=bip_time_limit)]

    _embed = [
        SetLayout(layout=layout),
        FullAncillaAllocation(coupling_map=coupling_map),
        EnlargeWithAncilla(),
        ApplyLayout(),
    ]

    _check_depth = [Depth(), FixedPoint('depth')]

    _optimize = [
        Collect2qBlocks(),
        ConsolidateBlocks(basis_gates=basis_gates),
        UnitarySynthesis(
            basis_gates=basis_gates,
            approximation_degree=synthesis_fidelity,
            coupling_map=coupling_map,
            backend_props=backend_props,
            pulse_optimize=pulse_optimize,
            natural_direction=True,
        ),
        Optimize1qGatesDecomposition(basis=basis_gates),
    ]

    _schedule = [
        ALAPSchedule(instruction_durations),
        DynamicalDecoupling(durations=instruction_durations, dd_sequence=[XGate(), XGate()]),
    ]

    pm = PassManager()
    # Map to a subset of qubits, by choosing layout and inserting swaps
    pm.append(_map)
    # Embed the mapped circuit onto the larger device coupling map
    pm.append(_embed)
    # Translate to and optimize over hardware native gates
    controller = DoWhileController(_check_depth + _optimize, do_while=_repeat_condition)
    pm.append(controller)
    # Dynamical decoupling on an as-late-as-possible schedule
    pm.append(_schedule)
    return pm


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService
    from qiskit.circuit.library import QuantumVolume

    service = QiskitRuntimeService()
    backend = service.backend('ibm_quebec')

    circuit = QuantumVolume(num_qubits=3, depth=3, seed=15).decompose()
    circuit.measure_all()

    coupling_map = CouplingMap(backend.configuration().coupling_map)
    instruction_durations = InstructionDurations.from_backend(backend)

    pm = qv_passmanager(
        basis_gates=backend.configuration().basis_gates,
        coupling_map=coupling_map,
        qubit_subset=[0, 1, 2],
        backend_props=backend.properties(),
        instruction_durations=instruction_durations,
        synthesis_fidelity=0.99,
        pulse_optimize=False,
        bip_time_limit=100,
    )

    circuit_compiled = pm.run(circuit)
    backend.run(circuit_compiled)

I am using Qiskit 0.46 since qiskit_bip_mapper does not support Qiskit 1.0, although if I swap the BIPMapping with, for example, qiskit.transpiler.passes.LookaheadSwap and use Qiskit 1.0, I still get the same error message. Any ideas about what is going wrong or how to fix this?
